# How to Draw a Horizontal Line in Java Swing

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

How does one draw a horizontal line using the Java Swing library?  I know that I need to override `paint(Graphics g)` but I am not sure what to put in the method.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
   // What goes here?
}
```

Comment: Have you tried here: http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=how+to+draw+horizontal+line+in+java+swing&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=8631cdd35a4d476d You might find useful links.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I have tried, and the second result was this question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on your use case, one of these tutorials should help you:

- The Java [Graphics API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) Tutorial => drawing in a swing component
- The Java [Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) Tutorial => using swing components (such as [JSeparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSeparator.html))

Here an example class which draws a Black line

```
public class MyLine extends JPanel
{

     @Override public void paint(Graphics g)
     {
         //Get the current size of this component
         Dimension d = this.getSize();

         //draw in black
         g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
         //draw a centered horizontal line
         g.drawLine(0,d.height/2,d.width,d.height/2);
     }
}
```

Comment: -1 for incorrectly overriding paint (which in itself is bad enought, in Swing, the method to override is paintComponent) without calling super

Answer (score -3):

Just like drawing any other line, except the value for the `y` axis doesn't change.

Comment: Actually this is only true in euclidean space :)